# Automate R script that use an ODBC using Windows batch

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio, rodbc

I am trying to automate this R code using Windows batch, it is named mail.R, executes a query in a database and sends mail with the info returned:

```
library(data.table)
library(htmlTable)
library(mailR)
library(DBI)
query <- "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPRLIBRANL.SAIALICTB"
odbccon <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "NACIONAL")
records  <- data.table(dbGetQuery(odbccon,query))
records <- as.integer(records$`00001`[1])
dbDisconnect(odbccon)
Table1 <- data.frame(
  Archive= c("SAIALICTB"),
  Records = c(records))
Table1 <- htmlTable(Table1, rnames = FALSE)
from1 <- "someone@xyz.com"
to1 <- c("someoneelse@xyz.com")
subject1 <- "Records in table"
body1 <- paste0("<html><head>
                 <style>
                 body{font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;}
                 table{border-left:1px solid #000000;border-top:1px solid #000000;}
                 table th{border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; margin: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0px;}
                 table td{border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:13px; font-weight:normal; margin: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0px;}
                 </style>
                 </head><body><p>The number of records in table SAIALICTB are:</p>",
                 Table1,
                 "</body></html>")
send.mail(from=from1,to=to1,subject=subject1,body=body1,smtp=list(host.name="some SMTP server",port=25),authenticate = FALSE,html=TRUE, send = TRUE)
```

Works fine when I execute it manually in RStudio, but when I use batch does not make anything. I am using this command to call the R code:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\"...path to file..."\mail.R"
```

I tried using **Rscript.exe** instead of **R.exe**, also changing **dbConnect** for **odbcConnect** in the **RODBC** package and nothing fix the problem.

Is something wrong with the ODBC creation when the R code is called from CMD?

Or, Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have R in your `PATH` environment variable, it's simply `rscript C:\path...\file.R`. If not, you need the full path to the R binary, but you should still use `rscript` as the executable. I don't think you need `CMD BATCH`

Comment: The full path would be `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\rscript.exe" "C:\"...path to file..."\mail.R"`

Comment: What is the error message? Or does it simply not do anything silently? Normally you use `Rscript --default-packages=methods,utils mail.R` to start a batch (see `?Rscript` for help - esp. the fact that the standard package `methods` is not loaded by default)

Answer (score 1):

Try taskscheduleR if you are working on Windows.

```
install.packages('taskscheduleR')
library(taskscheduleR)
```

After installing the package go to **Tools** > **Addins** > **Browse Addins** and then select **taskcheduleR**. After that you can set the specifications of your script. It also gives you the **logs of your script** so you can find what is going wrong on your script. **Even a single error causes scripts to quit.** You can find the logs file under the C:\~\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\taskscheduleR\extdata.

Hope it helps!